Why is start process minimized not working for some applications?
PowerShell code.
I tried these and they work properly:
Start-Process notepad -WindowStyle Minimized
Start-Process cmd -WindowStyle Minimized

But these do not work:
Start-Process control -WindowStyle Minimized
Start-Process calc -WindowStyle Minimized
Start-Process explorer -WindowStyle Minimized
Start-Process chrome -WindowStyle Minimized

why start minimized not work in some apps ?

This more-explicit command worked for me:
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -WindowStyle ([System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Minimized)

However, it didn't work for the other three programs.
The problem is that starting a program as minimized does nothing else
than preparing a request-block that include the parameters and the
startup conditions. It's up to the started process to honor this data,
but not all processes do so, or do so only partially.
A program that doesn't pay attention to the -WindowStyle Minimized
request will not minimize itself, and Windows will not (or cannot)
force the issue.
If you still want to minimize the program after it's launched,
you'll need to add more code to the PowerShell script to find
and minimize the launched process.

I tried your given code. Not work too in my PC. I will learn more to fix this problem.

For information see STARTUPINFOA structure, parameter wShowWindow, which points to ShowWindow function, parameter nCmdShow.
